# Error Trying To Call PHP Class

Tags: php, class, partial-classes

I am getting an error when tring to call a class

I have included the class in my Site Config File.

```
include($GLOBALS["webpath"] . "/classes/LM_com.php");
```

When i call for it I get An error that it cant be found. this is line 35

```
$loads = LM_com::GetLocationSearchCriteria($sql, $urlappend, "l");
```

error recieved

```
Fatal error: Class 'LM_com' not found in /home/{sitename}/public_html/pages/HotLoadSearchResults.php on line 35
```

Contents of the LM_com.php   class

```
<?php
if (!defined("LM_NS_CLASSES_INCLUDED"))
{
    define("LM_NS_CLASSES_INCLUDED", true);

    define("HIDE_ORIGIN_CITY",      (1 << 1));
    define("HIDE_ORIGIN_ZIP",       (1 << 2));
    define("HIDE_DESTINATION_CITY", (1 << 3));
    define("HIDE_DESTINATION_ZIP",  (1 << 4));
    define("HIDE_DESTINATION",      (1 << 5));
    define("ARCHIVE_POST",          (1 << 6));

    $GLOBALS["StatusMessages"] = array(
        "Company Deleted.",         // 0 
        "Company Activated.", 
        "Load Posted.",             // 2
        "Load Updated.", 
        "Load Deleted.",            // 4
        "Truck Posted.",
        "Truck Updated.",           // 6
        "Truck Deleted.",
        "User Deactivated.",        // 8
        "User Activated.",
        "Passwords don't match.",   // 10
        "Password Changed.",
        "User Deleted.",            // 12
        "Error Activating User.",
        "Error Deactivating User.", // 14
        "Error Deleting User.",
        "News Posted.",             // 16
        "Error Posting News.",
        "News Post Deleted.",       // 18
        "Error Deleting News Post.",
        "User Profile Updated.",    // 20
        "Error Updating User Profile.",
        "Company Profile Updated.", // 22
        "Error Updating Company Profile.",
        "User Moved.",              // 24
        "Error Moving User.",   
        "Error Adding User.",       // 26
        "User Added.",
        "Company Added.",           // 28
        "Error Adding Company.",
        "Email Sent.",              // 30
        "No Emails Sent.",
        "Cannot Add Blacklisted Email Address.",  // 32
        "Bid Placed.",
        "Bid Not Placed."           // 34
    );

    class UserOwnedObject
    {
        var $UserID = -1;
        // does this session's user own this object?
        function IsUserOwner()
        {
            if ($this->UserID == -1)
                return false;
            if (!isset($_SESSION["user"]) || !$_SESSION["user"]->IsLoggedIn())
                return false;
            //if ($_SESSION["user"]->CheckPrivs("admin", "canDelete"))
            //  return true;
            if ($this->UserID == $_SESSION["user"]->UserID)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    function hex2asc($myin) 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($myin) / 2; $i++) 
        {
            $myout .= chr(base_convert(substr($myin, $i*2, 2), 16, 10));
        }
        return $myout;
    }

    // get the administrative email address for the site
    // search order: config db, site-conf setting, Administrator user email address
    function get_admin_email()
    {
        $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
        $toaddr = "";
        // try getting admin email from config table first
        $sql = "SELECT ConfigValue FROM config WHERE ConfigName = 'admin_email'";
        $conf = &$conn->Execute($sql);
        if ($conf->RecordCount() > 0)
            $toaddr = $conf->fields[0];
        else if (!empty($GLOBALS["site_AdminEmail"])) // try falling back on site-conf setting
        {
            $toaddr = $GLOBALS["site_AdminEmail"];
        }
        else // last resort, look for a user named Administrator
        {
            // toaddr email address should come from username = 'Administrator'
            $sql = "SELECT Email FROM users WHERE UserName = 'Administrator'";
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($sql);
            if ($rs === false) 
                die("internal error:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $sql);
            $toaddr = $rs->fields[0];
        }
        return $toaddr;
    }

    // this is a big chunk of search results code that's used for both loads & trucks







    function GetEquipmentSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        // if no equipment search options given, use 0 to mean any equipment matches
        if (!isset($GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]) || empty($GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]))
            $GLOBALS["EquipmentID"] = array();
        // make the equipmentid list an array if it isn't one
        if (!is_array($GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]))
            $GLOBALS["EquipmentID"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]);

        $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();

        // if there are any equipment search options, prepare the sql append
        if (sizeof($GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]) > 0)
        {
            $gsql = "SELECT EquipmentID, SearchGroup FROM equipment WHERE EquipmentID IN (" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]) . ")";
            $groups = $conn->Execute($gsql);
            $search_ids = "";
            while (!$groups->EOF)
            {
                if (!empty($search_ids))
                    $search_ids .= ",";
                $search_ids .= $groups->fields[1];
                $groups->MoveNext();
            }
            if (!empty($search_ids))
                $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".EquipmentID IN ( " . $search_ids . ")";
        }

        // do the same thing for lengths now

        // if no length search options given, use 0 to mean any length matches
        if (!isset($GLOBALS["Length"]) || empty($GLOBALS["Length"]))
            $GLOBALS["Length"] = array();
        // make the length list an array if it isn't one
        if (!is_array($GLOBALS["Length"]))
            $GLOBALS["Length"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["Length"]);
        // if there are any length search options, prepare the sql append
        if (sizeof($GLOBALS["Length"]) > 0)
        {
            $gsql = "SELECT LengthID, SearchGroup FROM length WHERE LengthID IN (" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["Length"]) . ")";
            $len_groups = $conn->Execute($gsql);
            if ($len_groups === false)
                die($conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $gsql);
            $group_ids = "";
            while (!$len_groups->EOF)
            {
                if (!empty($group_ids))
                    $group_ids .= ",";
                $group_ids .= $len_groups->fields[1];
                $len_groups->MoveNext();
            }
            if (!empty($group_ids))
                $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".LengthID IN ( " . $group_ids . ")";
        }

        $urlappend .= "&EquipmentID=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["EquipmentID"]) . 
                      "&Length=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["Length"]);
    }







    function GetLocationSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        $origin_id = Location::GetLocationID($GLOBALS["OriginState"], $GLOBALS["OriginCity"], $GLOBALS["OriginZip"]);
        $destination_id = Location::GetLocationID($GLOBALS["DestinationState"], $GLOBALS["DestinationCity"], $GLOBALS["DestinationZip"]);

        if (!is_array($origin_id))
        {
            $o = $origin_id;
            $origin_id = array();
            $origin_id[0] = $o;
        }
        if (!is_array($destination_id))
        {
            $d = $destination_id;
            $destination_id = array();
            $destination_id[0] = $d;
        }

        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginRadius"]))
        {
            $origin = new Location($origin_id[0]);
            $origin_id = $origin->GetRadiusLocations($GLOBALS["OriginRadius"]);
            $urlappend .= "&OriginRadius=" . $GLOBALS["OriginRadius"];
        }
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationRadius"]))
        {
            $destination = new Location($destination_id[0]);
            $destination_id = $destination->GetRadiusLocations($GLOBALS["DestinationRadius"]);
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationRadius=" . $GLOBALS["DestinationRadius"];
        }

        // remember search params
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginState"]))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginState=" . $GLOBALS["OriginState"];
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginCity"]))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginCity=" . $GLOBALS["OriginCity"];
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginZip"]))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginZip=" . $GLOBALS["OriginZip"];

        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationState"]))
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationState=" . $GLOBALS["DestinationState"];
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationCity"]))
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationCity=" . $GLOBALS["DestinationCity"];
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationZip"]))
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationZip=" . $GLOBALS["DestinationZip"];

        // build query
        if ($origin_id[0] != -1)
            $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".OriginLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $origin_id) . ") ";

        if ($destination_id[0] != -1)
            $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".DestinationLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $destination_id) . ") ";
    }








        function GetLocationSearchCriteria1(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        $origin_id = Location::GetMultiLocationID($GLOBALS["OriginState"]);
        $destination_id = Location::GetMultiLocationID($GLOBALS["DestinationState"]);

        if (!is_array($origin_id))
        {
            $o = $origin_id;
            $origin_id = array();
            $origin_id[0] = $o;
        }
        if (!is_array($destination_id))
        {
            $d = $destination_id;
            $destination_id = array();
            $destination_id[0] = $d;
        }

        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginRadius"]))
        {
            $origin = new Location($origin_id[0]);
            $origin_id = $origin->GetRadiusLocations($GLOBALS["OriginRadius"]);
            $urlappend .= "&OriginRadius=" . $GLOBALS["OriginRadius"];
        }
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationRadius"]))
        {
            $destination = new Location($destination_id[0]);
            $destination_id = $destination->GetRadiusLocations($GLOBALS["DestinationRadius"]);
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationRadius=" . $GLOBALS["DestinationRadius"];
        }

        // remember search params
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginState"]))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginState=" . $GLOBALS["OriginState"];

        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationState"]))
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationState=" . $GLOBALS["DestinationState"];

        // build query
        if ($origin_id[0] != -1)
            $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".OriginLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $origin_id) . ") ";

        if ($destination_id[0] != -1)
            $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".DestinationLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $destination_id) . ") ";
    }











    function GetMultiLocationSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        $state_vals = array();
        $city_vals = array();
        $zip_vals = array();
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginState"]))
        {
            $GLOBALS["OriginState"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["OriginState"]);
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM locations WHERE StateInitials IN ('" . implode("','", $GLOBALS["OriginState"]) . "')";
            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($s);
            if ($rs === false) die("panic:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $s);
            $vals = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF) 
            {
                array_push($vals, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            $state_vals = $vals;
        }
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginCity"]))
        {
            $GLOBALS["OriginCity"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["OriginCity"]);
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM locations WHERE City IN ('" . implode("','", $GLOBALS["OriginCity"]) . "')";
            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($s);
            if ($rs === false) die("panic:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $s);
            $vals = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF) 
            {
                array_push($vals, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            $city_vals = $vals;
        }
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginZip"]))
        {
            $GLOBALS["OriginZip"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["OriginZip"]);
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM locations WHERE ZipCode IN ('" . implode("','", $GLOBALS["OriginZip"]) . "')";
            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($s);
            if ($rs === false) die("panic:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $s);
            $vals = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF) 
            {
                array_push($vals, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            $zip_vals = $vals;
        }

        // remember search params
        if (!empty($state_vals))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginState=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["OriginState"]);
        if (!empty($city_vals))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginCity=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["OriginCity"]);
        if (!empty($zip_vals))
            $urlappend .= "&OriginZip=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["OriginZip"]);
        // build query
        $vals = array_unique(array_merge($state_vals, $city_vals, $zip_vals));
        if (!empty($vals))
            $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".OriginLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $vals) . ") ";

        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationState"]))
        {
            $GLOBALS["DestinationState"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["DestinationState"]);
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM locations WHERE StateInitials IN ('" . implode("','", $GLOBALS["DestinationState"]) . "')";
            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($s);
            if ($rs === false) die("panic:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $s);
            $vals = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF) 
            {
                array_push($vals, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            if (!empty($vals))
            {
                $sql .= " AND ";
                $sql .= $prefix . ".DestinationLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $vals) . ") ";
            }
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationState=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["DestinationState"]);
        }
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationCity"]))
        {
            $GLOBALS["DestinationCity"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["DestinationCity"]);
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM locations WHERE City IN ('" . implode("','", $GLOBALS["DestinationCity"]) . "')";
            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($s);
            if ($rs === false) die("panic:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $s);
            $vals = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF) 
            {
                array_push($vals, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            if (!empty($vals))
                $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".DestinationLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $vals) . ") ";
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationCity=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["DestinationCity"]);
        }
        if (!empty($GLOBALS["DestinationZip"]))
        {
            $GLOBALS["DestinationZip"] = explode(",", $GLOBALS["DestinationZip"]);
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM locations WHERE ZipCode IN ('" . implode("','", $GLOBALS["DestinationZip"]) . "')";
            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($s);
            if ($rs === false) die("panic:" . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $s);
            $vals = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF) 
            {
                array_push($vals, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            if (!empty($vals))
                $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".DestinationLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $vals) . ") ";
            $urlappend .= "&DestinationZip=" . implode(",", $GLOBALS["DestinationZip"]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Change the `include` to a `require` - is it successfully included?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the "LM_com.php" file?  Also, try echoing the value of `$GLOBALS['webpath']` to make sure it is what you expect it is.

Comment: there is the contents of the file... and i tried changing include to require and didnt work webpath is fine i call other classes in same page as well...

Comment: Well from looking at the contents of the file it looks like no class named LM_com is actually in the file. In the PHP manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php it defines a class as having class before it similar to the UserOwnedObject in your code. Nowhere else in the file you posted do I see an LM_com class defined. However there is a function defined for `GetLocationSearchCriteria` if you used `GetLocationSearchCriteria($sql, $urlappend, "l");` it would probably work.

Comment: I did that now i guess i need to check the coding because seems that it is not using that function

Comment: you don't have a 'valid' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you don't have a class defined named LM_com in the code you have posted. 
A proper class is contained in a class structure like that posted below.

```
class lm_com
{
    public function hex2asc($myin) 
    {
       // ...
    }

    public function get_admin_email()
    {
       // ...
    }

    public function GetEquipmentSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
       // ...
    }

    public function GetLocationSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
       // ...
    }

    public function GetLocationSearchCriteria1(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function GetMultiLocationSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Secondly you have attempted to call a method in a class using the syntax with a double colon className::methodName.

This syntax when used outside of a class structure only works when calling static class methods. Static class methods do not require creating an instance of the class before calling those methods.

The following format is used for defining a public static method that can be called without creating an instance of the class

```
public static function GetLocationSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
{
    // ...
}
```

After you have defined the class and method as I've described then you'll be able to properly make a call to `LM_com::GetLocationSearchCriteria($sql, $urlappend, "l");`